# Node Server return Promise

Tags: node.js, callback, server

I am a beginner and can hardly understand promises or callbacks,how can I return the data below so my home server can respond to requests
thanks for any help

```
else if(requests["mode"]==="onlineVideoQuery"){
var title = requests["title"].replace(/\+/g," ")

imdb.get(title).then(function(data) {
console.log(data)
//I need to get this data above for response.end(data)
});

response.end("how can I return the data above to this response")
}
```

Comment: Can you post more code to see more of what you trying to do?

Comment: just put `response.end` in your promise callback ( `.....then( function(data) { response.end( data ) ) ` )

Comment: its a server,like localhost:8080/?mode=onlineVideoQuery&title=friends,I want it to respond with the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the response.end in the `then` function:

```
...
else if (requests["mode"] === "onlineVideoQuery") {
  var title = requests["title"].replace(/\+/g, " ")

  imdb.get(title).then(function(data) {
    response.end(data)
  });
}
```

Make sure call response.end once por request, and to don't mix async code with sync code, that could generate a race condition.

Comment: thanks,silly mistake the data is JSON,and I was getting an error,because it was not a string,thats why I was so confused,thanks for your help

Comment: strangely console.log logs the stringified object so I thought the data was a string,but it was an object,I thought logging an object would return [object],learned something their I guess

Comment: you have to JSON.stringify(data) explicitly. `console.log` uses `util.format` to display data and it may differ.